# Concurrent update on two different tables fail

Tags: postgresql, update, subquery, deadlock, where

I'm using PostgreSQL with the following database schema:

```
CREATE TABLE plans (
    slug VARCHAR(500) PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE users (
    id VARCHAR(16) PRIMARY KEY,
    org_id VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE orgs (
    id VARCHAR(16) PRIMARY KEY,
    plan_slug VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
    last_write_at DOUBLE PRECISION
);
```

In my case, I want to write a query to update some org's `plan_slug` and protect it from other possible concurrent update.
To do this, I use a `SELECT` in a subquery and a `FOR UPDATE` to lock the rows in a specific order to avoid deadlocks.
Like the following query:

```
UPDATE orgs
SET plan_slug = 'plan_1'
WHERE id = ANY(
    SELECT subquery_orgs.id
    FROM orgs AS subquery_orgs
    JOIN users ON users.org_id = subquery_orgs.id
    WHERE users.id = ANY('{user_1, user_2, user_3}')
    ORDER BY subquery_orgs.id
    FOR UPDATE
);
```

I noticed that if this request takes a long time to run, there is a high chance of collision with another query that is trying to update the `last_write_at` of an org (an org that is already being updated by the first query).

As follows:

```
UPDATE orgs 
SET last_write_at = 999 
FROM plans 
WHERE orgs.id = 'org_1';
```

The query will succeed. But if I add the `plan_slug` in the `WHERE` clause of the query, it will always fail to update. Postgre return `UPDATE 0`.

The query is the following:

```
UPDATE orgs 
SET last_write_at = 999 
FROM plans 
WHERE orgs.id = 'org_1' 
AND plans.slug = orgs.plan_slug;
```

From what I understand the process should be:

1. The first query execute. The `plan_slug` row is locked.
2. The second query execute. It stops its execution and wait for the row to unlock.
3. The first query finishes its update.
4. The second query restart and re-evaluate the changes.
5. The `plan_slug` has changed but the new one exist in the `plans` table, the second query should succeed.

Then why the query is failing to update when I add the `plan_slug` to the `WHERE` clause ?

Comment: Being there is no foreign key constraint from `orgs.plan_slug` to `plans.slug`, there is no guarantee that `plans.slug = orgs.plan_slug` matches anything. In fact, query #1 may have broken that relationship, thus why query #3 finds nothing to update.

Comment: In fact in my case the `plans.slug` always match `orgs.plan_slug`. The `slug` is checked in the code to be an existing row in the `plans` table.
Also I tried your solution by adding a foreign key constraint but unfortunately it did not solve the problem.

Comment: I can reproduce the behavior you've described by hand with two `psql` sessions. Now to figure out what exactly is happening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Related question

- [Inconsistent data when combining (LEFT) JOIN with SELECT FOR UPDATE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/312261/inconsistent-data-when-combining-left-join-with-select-for-update)

## Problem

Your summation of the process is correct, until step 4. The query does not *restart* after the locks are taken; the modified row **versions** are read and replace the old row versions. Before the locks were taken, a table join had occurred, and the new row versions render the join nonsensical and the rows are discarded.

Here is my revised version of events:

1. The first query starts execution. The rows in `orgs` are locked.
2. The second query starts execution.

   a. `UPDATE` reads the *old* row versions from `orgs` and `plans` (ignoring #1, as it has not `COMMIT` yet).

   b. `UPDATE` performs the join on `orgs` and `plans` and qualifies `orgs.id` to build the target row list.

   c. `UPDATE` tries to lock the targeted rows `FOR NO KEY SHARE` and blocks on the first query's `FOR UPDATE` lock.
3. The first query `COMMIT`.
4. The second query unblocks and notices the rows it had targeted have changed.

   a. The new row versions are read and *replace* the existing row versions in the join.

   b. The conditions are re-evaluated, and now the join condition fails as `orgs.plan_slug` has changed and no longer matches the `plans` row it previously joined to. The rows are discarded.
5. The second query finds no rows to target with `UPDATE`.

To show it graphically:

- The second query starts with the join looking like:

  | id | plan_slug | last_write_at | slug |
  | --- | --- | --- | --- |
  | user_1 | plan_1 | 888 | plan_1 |
- First query completes, `orgs.plan_slug` changes from `plan_1` to `plan_2`.
- The second query resumes, reads the `orgs` row versions, and changes its join state to:

  | id | plan_slug | last_write_at | slug |
  | --- | --- | --- | --- |
  | user_1 | plan_2 | 888 | plan_1 |
- Second query now re-evaluates its `WHERE` conditions. Uh oh, `plan_2` != `plan_1`, rows are discarded.

## Solutions

1. Don't use `FROM plans` in your `UPDATE last_write_at...`. To be honest, I don't understand what its purpose is in your query; the column in `plans` is not referenced in any meaningful way. I assume there was more going on there that was deleted for the purposes of simplifying the question. Perhaps you can update the question to elucidate why it is that way.
2. Use isolation level `REPEATABLE READ` with your `UPDATE last_write_at...` transaction. At that level, instead of updating no rows, you get the error `ERROR:  could not serialize access due to concurrent update`. You can abort and retry the transaction knowing it is getting fresh data.
3. Use a previous `SELECT .. FOR UPDATE` in the transaction to lock rows before `UPDATE`. Then `UPDATE` never has to contend with rows changing out from under it. In PL/pgSQL, you can use `PERFORM 1 ... FOR UPDATE` instead to avoid outputting the rows. As an example:

   ```
   BEGIN;
   SELECT id FROM orgs WHERE id='org_1' FOR UPDATE;
   UPDATE orgs SET last_write_at = 999 FROM plans 
     WHERE orgs.id = 'org_1' AND plans.slug = orgs.plan_slug;
   COMMIT;
   ```

## Credits

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/11568880 - for the breakdown of the steps (not 100% applicable but enough to get an idea)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/57865346 - mentions `PERFORM 1 ...`

Comment: Thank you for this very clear explanation.
I decided to go for the first solution. Actually, I already knew that this solution would work but I wanted to understand why.
However, I couldn't get the third solution to work.

Comment: Added an example of the transaction in solution #3.